# Applications of Jack polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

I developed a [Julia package](https://github.com/stla/JackPolynomials.jl) for the computation of Jack polynomials. The zonal polynomials are particular cases ($\alpha=2$) of Jack polynomials (up to a renormalization), and they have some applications in multivariate statistics. The Schur polynomials are particular cases ($\alpha=1$) of Jack polynomials and they have some applications in combinatorics. I'm wondering whether there are some applications of Jack polynomials other than Zonal or Schur polynomials. Nothing is said about the applications on Wikipedia, and I haven't be able to find this information elsewhere. Would you know such an application?